# Use least squares to find best fit value of angle phi

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> Given initial object $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ and final object $\begin{bmatrix}0.9557 & 0.0965 & 0.9648\\-0.3381 & 0.0158 & 1.8977\end{bmatrix}$ after rotation with a certain angle $\phi$. There was a perturbation during the rotation so that there is no exact solution. Using least squares to find the best value of $\phi$.

---

So far I have
\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0.9557 & 0.0965 & 0.9648\\-0.3381 & 0.0158 & 1.8977
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  \rightarrow
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0.9557 & 0.0965 & 0.9648\\-0.3381 & 0.0158 & 1.8977
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  \rightarrow
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0\\ 0 & 4
  \end{bmatrix} & =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0.9557 & 1.9296\\
  -0.3381 & 3.7954
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  \rightarrow
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
  \end{bmatrix}&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0.9557 & 0.4824\\
  -0.3381 & 0.9488
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}

At this step, I don't know how to find the angle $\phi$, can someone give me a hint or a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're proceeding as if the four entry of the rotation matrix were independent quantities. Instead you need to minimize the sum of squares of the errors in the matrix entries:

$$
\pmatrix{\cos\phi&\sin\phi\\-\sin\phi&\cos\phi}\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&2}=\pmatrix{\cos\phi&0&2\sin\phi\\-\sin\phi&0&2\cos\phi}\;.
$$

The errors in the middle column don't depend on $\phi$, so we can ignore them and minimize

\begin{align}
&(\cos\phi-0.9557)^2+(-\sin\phi+0.3381)^2+(2\sin\phi-0.9648)^2+(2\cos\phi-1.8977)^2\\
={}&2\left(-0.9557\cos\phi-0.3381\sin\phi-2\cdot0.9648\sin\phi-2\cdot1.8977\cos\phi\right)+\textsf{const.}
\end{align}

Setting the derivative with respect to $\phi$ to zero yields

$$
4.7511\sin\phi-2.2677\cos\phi=0\;,
$$

so $\phi=\textsf{atan2}(2.2677,4.7511)\approx0.44532$, so the best fit matrix is approximately

$$
\pmatrix{0.9025&0&0.7775\\-0.4307&0&1.8049}\;.
$$

Comment: @Simple: Use $\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi=1$.

Comment: Why do we minimize the sum of squares of the errors?

Comment: @Simple: Because the question asked "Use least squares to find best fit value".

Comment: I mean in the second equation, why do we just get the sum of squares, not a matrix in the form $A^TAx=A^Tb$? This is the form I know for least suqares

Comment: @Simple: That's linear least squares. It's the solution for the best approximation for $Ax=b$, and you get that solution precisely in the same ways as I got the solution here, by setting the derivative of the sum of squares of the errors with respect to all variables to zero. In the present case you're not doing linear least squares so you don't get the same solution as for linear least squares.

Comment: Is this nonlinear?

Comment: @Simple: Are the sine and cosine non-linear?

Comment: yes, it is. And I think there is an error in the second equality in your answer.

Comment: @Simple: Are you going to let me guess what it is? :-)

Comment: you should have $-\sin(\phi)+0.3381$, :-)

Comment: @Simple: You're right -- I corrected that, and it looks like it improved the fit.

Comment: I would keep the errors on the RSQ, or otherwise we are biasing the solution somewhat. It might be reasonable to subtract a constant from the errors vector, but not subtract different values from different elements of ${\rm Vector}({\rm Rot(\phi)}A-B)$.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. You have ${\rm Rot}(\phi) \approx A$

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
  \end{bmatrix} \approx
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0.9557 & 0.4824\\
  -0.3381 & 0.9488
  \end{bmatrix} $$

To filter out the perturbations you need to find the smallest coefficients that create an exact relationship like this

$$  A= \begin{bmatrix}
  0.9557 & 0.4824\\
  -0.3381 & 0.9488
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{bmatrix} + (1+s) \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
  \end{bmatrix}  $$

Start by splitting $A$ (the LHS) it into symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices.

$$ \frac{A+A^\top}{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.9557 & 0.07215 \\ 0.07215 & 0.94885 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.952275 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.952275 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0.003425 & 0.07215 \\ 0.07215& -0.003425 \end{bmatrix} $$

To find the diagonal terms I divided by two the trace (average of two diagonal values). The last part on the right is the perturbation $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix} $.

Now I can write

$$ A =  \begin{bmatrix} 0.003425 & 0.07215 \\ 0.07215& -0.003425 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0.952275& 0.41025 \\-0.41025 & 0.952275 \end{bmatrix} = P + M$$

The second part is skew symmetric, but not orthonormal. So we can write

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 0.952275& 0.41025 \\-0.41025 & 0.952275 \end{bmatrix} = (1+s) \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) \end{bmatrix} $$

By pre-multiplying with the transpose each side we have the expression $$M^\top M = (1+s)^2 \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Which yields the reasonable value of $s=0.0368861$

Now we have $$ \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) \end{bmatrix} = \frac{M}{1+s} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.91839886799684497 & 0.39565580908425155 \\ -0.39565580908425155 & 0.91839886799684497 \end{bmatrix}$$

This has the unique solution of $\tan(\phi) = 0.43081$ or $$ \boxed{ \phi = 0.40678182 + n \pi } $$

### Confirmation

This is a solution because

$$  \begin{bmatrix} \cos(0.4068) & \sin(0.4068)\\ -\sin(0.4068) & \cos(0.4068) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.9184 & 0 & 0.7913 \\ -0.3957 & 0 & 1.8368 \end{bmatrix} \approx  \begin{bmatrix} 0.9557 & 0.0965 & 0.9648\\ -0.3381 & 0.0158 & 1.8977 \end{bmatrix} $$

the error is minimized.

Comment: I want to know what $s $ is.

Comment: $s$ is a scale in order to make the $M$ matrix orthonormal ($M^\top M = \mathtt{1}$) and thus like a rotation matrix. By pulling the skew symmetric part out of $A$ we have _almost_ a rotation, except for the scaling factor $1+s$. Again we want to minimize $s$, or at least be happy it is small value.